# R - multiple nested for in loop not fully populating in dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe, for-loop

I am trying to create a dataframe that has output from a function that takes into account two different 'character' arguments. I am using a for in loop, but it is only populating the dataframe with the last character of the last argument. Can you please help me? My code includes first making a siber object, and then doing the for in loop. See below:

First, here are the R packages I have in my code: "tidyverse","SIBER","GGally","reshape2"

Here is my data that I work with.

```
     iso1 iso2 group community
1   -8.75 8.87     a         z
2   -9.21 8.53     a         z
3   -8.52 8.32     a         z
4  -10.69 5.79     a         z
5  -10.08 7.67     a         z
6  -14.88 7.16     a         z
7  -15.22 6.43     a         z
8  -14.09 6.70     a         z
9  -14.84 6.80     a         z
10 -13.76 6.40     a         z
11 -14.10 5.79     a         z
12 -13.92 6.16     a         z
13 -12.11 6.07     a         z
14 -14.48 6.48     a         z
15 -10.33 6.45     a         z
16 -10.85 7.01     a         z
17 -11.75 6.62     a         z
18 -11.64 6.78     a         z
19 -11.60 4.97     a         z
20 -11.91 7.86     a         z
21 -11.34 6.68     a         z
22  -9.80 7.78     a         z
23 -11.19 7.43     a         z
24 -10.74 6.85     a         z
25 -10.57 7.16     a         z
26 -10.29 5.71     a         z
27 -11.21 7.80     a         z
28 -11.69 7.85     a         z
29 -10.89 7.62     a         z
30 -10.18 4.73     b         z
31  -9.20 6.63     b         z
32 -14.28 5.47     b         z
33 -12.80 4.21     b         z
34 -14.87 5.72     b         z
35 -12.43 6.13     b         z
36 -12.60 5.02     b         z
37 -11.06 5.06     b         z
38 -10.65 5.63     b         z
39 -13.69 2.95     c         z
40 -13.19 2.41     c         z
41 -14.41 3.11     c         z
42 -11.47 4.88     d         z
43 -11.73 4.79     d         z
44 -12.62 5.59     d         z
45 -11.57 3.63     e         z
46 -11.79 2.75     e         z
47 -12.67 4.93     f         z
48 -12.50 5.09     f         z
49 -13.18 5.11     f         z
50 -12.71 5.36     f         z
51 -10.24 5.49     f         z
52 -10.10 4.46     f         z
53 -10.54 4.09     f         z
54 -10.46 4.22     f         z
55 -11.05 4.78     f         z
56 -11.08 4.67     f         z
57 -11.64 4.19     f         z
58 -11.61 4.82     f         z
59 -11.22 4.50     f         z
60  -6.00 1.29     g         z
61  -7.30 4.08     g         z
62  -7.30 1.68     g         z
63  -6.90 1.87     g         z
64  -8.10 1.13     g         z
65  -5.10 2.54     g         z
66  -6.90 2.38     g         z
67  -6.50 4.00     g         z
68  -7.10 3.60     g         z
69  -5.30 2.31     g         z
70  -7.30 3.97     g         z
71  -4.20 1.03     g         z
72 -10.50 2.85     g         z
73  -8.68 2.61     g         z
74  -8.04 3.06     g         z
75 -14.33 2.13     e         z
76 -12.05 2.21     e         z
77 -12.06 2.45     e         z
78 -13.18 2.84     e         z
79 -12.26 1.35     e         z
80 -13.14 3.01     e         z
81 -14.20 3.55     e         z
82 -13.56 3.36     e         z
83 -11.98 2.93     e         z
84 -14.49 2.68     e         z
85 -14.45 3.00     e         z
86 -15.08 2.32     e         z
```

Here is my code, note: the df1 and df2 are a combination of the "community" and "group" variable in my data that are needed as that is how they are listed in the siber.test object I made.

```
siber.test = createSiberObject(si.test)

df1 <- data.frame(c("z.a","z.b","z.c","z.d","z.e","z.f","z.g"))
df2 <- data.frame(c("z.a","z.b"))

mylist <- list() #create an empty list
for (i in 1:nrow(df1)) {
  for (j in 1:nrow(df2)) {
    
    ij.overlap <- maxLikOverlap(df1[i,],df2[j,], siber.test, 
                                p.interval = NULL, n = 100)
    ij.over=ij.overlap[3]/(ij.overlap[2]+ij.overlap[1]-ij.overlap[3])
    vec=c(df1[i,],df2[j,],ij.overlap,ij.over)
    mylist[[i]]=vec
  }
}
df=do.call("rbind",mylist)
```

Right now, the code only gives me a dataframe with just the last combination of df2, see below:

```
                 area.1              area.2             overlap                overlap               
[1,] "z.a" "z.b" "4.93603972039955"  "4.89919820826708" "0.0841731887902768"   "0.00863220489615416" 
[2,] "z.b" "z.b" "4.89919820826708"  "4.89919820826708" "4.89919820826767"     "1.00000000000024"    
[3,] "z.c" "z.b" "0.559725304862695" "4.89919820826708" "9.54097911787244e-18" "1.74777666236292e-18"
[4,] "z.d" "z.b" "0.522204858582882" "4.89919820826708" "0.45393111227755"     "0.0913807096303221"  
[5,] "z.e" "z.b" "2.49971788496032"  "4.89919820826708" "4.85722573273506e-17" "6.56478012662033e-18"
[6,] "z.f" "z.b" "1.38774348908464"  "4.89919820826708" "0.742263994748963"    "0.133869637616724"   
[7,] "z.g" "z.b" "5.21007280975346"  "4.89919820826708" "0"                    "0"
```

instead, what I want to get, but the code won't show me is the following:

```
                 area.1              area.2             overlap                overlap               
[1,] "z.a" "z.a" "4.93603972039955"  "4.93603972039955" "4.93603972040026"     "1.00000000000029"    
[2,] "z.b" "z.a" "4.89919820826708"  "4.93603972039955" "0.0841731887902741"   "0.00863220489615387" 
[3,] "z.c" "z.a" "0.559725304862695" "4.93603972039955" "8.67361737988404e-18" "1.57823657671211e-18"
[4,] "z.d" "z.a" "0.522204858582882" "4.93603972039955" "6.93889390390723e-18" "1.27126840937583e-18"
[5,] "z.e" "z.a" "2.49971788496032"  "4.93603972039955" "2.77555756156289e-17" "3.73271656887014e-18"
[6,] "z.f" "z.a" "1.38774348908464"  "4.93603972039955" "3.64291929955129e-17" "5.76066442962145e-18"
[7,] "z.g" "z.a" "5.21007280975346"  "4.93603972039955" "0"                    "0"   
[8,] "z.a" "z.b" "4.93603972039955"  "4.89919820826708" "0.0841731887902768"   "0.00863220489615416" 
[9,] "z.b" "z.b" "4.89919820826708"  "4.89919820826708" "4.89919820826767"     "1.00000000000024"    
[10,] "z.c" "z.b" "0.559725304862695" "4.89919820826708" "9.54097911787244e-18" "1.74777666236292e-18"
[11,] "z.d" "z.b" "0.522204858582882" "4.89919820826708" "0.45393111227755"     "0.0913807096303221"  
[12,] "z.e" "z.b" "2.49971788496032"  "4.89919820826708" "4.85722573273506e-17" "6.56478012662033e-18"
[13,] "z.f" "z.b" "1.38774348908464"  "4.89919820826708" "0.742263994748963"    "0.133869637616724"   
[14,] "z.g" "z.b" "5.21007280975346"  "4.89919820826708" "0"                    "0"
```

After the several helpful comments from below, I followed the recommendation to instead make a dataframe that then gets incorporated into mylist. Note, I had to add a transpose function t() inside of the tmpframe arguments for ij.overlap and ij.over because they have 3 value outputs that otherwise would make new rows for each value output.

```
siber.test = createSiberObject(si.test)

df1 <- data.frame(c("z.a","z.b","z.c","z.d","z.e","z.f","z.g"))
df2 <- data.frame(c("z.a","z.b"))

mylist <- list() #create an empty list
for (i in 1:nrow(df1)) {
  for (j in 1:nrow(df2)) {
    
    ij.overlap <- maxLikOverlap(df1[i,],df2[j,], siber.test, 
                                p.interval = NULL, n = 100)
    ij.over=ij.overlap[3]/(ij.overlap[2]+ij.overlap[1]-ij.overlap[3])
    tmpframe <- data.frame(df1[i,],df2[j,],t(ij.overlap),t(ij.over))
    mylist <- c(mylist, list(tmpframe))
  }
}
df=do.call("rbind",mylist)
```

Comment: Your last to blocks are not frames, they are matrices. This is why you are _corrupting_ your data: all elements of a matrix must be the same class, so when you set one to a string, all numbers become strings.

Comment: Your `mylist[[i]]=vec` is overwriting its contents for each `j`, so `mylist[[i]]` ends with just the last results; you'd get the same truncated results if your `j` loop were `for (j in nrow(df2))` (a single pass).

Comment: oh, I voted up the answer that I used, instead of clicking the 'check' button for accept. My bad, should be good now.

Comment: Thank you for accepting this one, but I was honestly trying to support those who have answered you before (some could use the rep ;-). Please consider taking a moment to accept others given to you as well on your [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8721584/catcool7?tab=questions). Thanks for the extra effort, I'm sure they'll appreciate it too!

Comment: Yep, done, I see what you mean now, thanks.

Comment: That's awesome, catcool7, thanks for doing that!

Comment: (FYI, for the self-answered question, you can accept your own answer, that's perfectly acceptable.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't have `SIBER`, but perhaps this will work: it first creates an expansion on each from `df1` and `df2`, then runs the function on each pair.

We can use `mapply` (to replace your two `for` loops); this returns a matrix here (needing to be `t`ranposed, easy enough), which is okay because the return value from `maxLikOverlap` is a numeric vector length-3.

```r
eg <- expand.grid(
  a = c("z.a","z.b","z.c","z.d","z.e","z.f","z.g"),
  b = c("z.a","z.b"),
  stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
eg
#      a   b
# 1  z.a z.a
# 2  z.b z.a
# 3  z.c z.a
# 4  z.d z.a
# 5  z.e z.a
# 6  z.f z.a
# 7  z.g z.a
# 8  z.a z.b
# 9  z.b z.b
# 10 z.c z.b
# 11 z.d z.b
# 12 z.e z.b
# 13 z.f z.b
# 14 z.g z.b

res <- t(mapply(function(a, b) maxLikOverlap(a, b, siber.test, p.interval = NULL, n = 100), 
                eg$a, eg$b))
```

From here, you can call `cbind(eg, data.frame(res))`, and you'll now have columns `X1` through `X3` (or is the vector returned from `maxLikOverlap` named?), which you can name what you prefer.

`mapply` calls the function (its first argument, with as many named arguments as you want to pass to the rest of `mapply`) for each pair of the vector/lists you provide later. For instance, it "unrolls" to

```r
maxLikOverlap("z.a", "z.a", siber.test, p.interval = NULL, n = 100)
maxLikOverlap("z.b", "z.a", siber.test, p.interval = NULL, n = 100)
maxLikOverlap("z.c", "z.a", siber.test, p.interval = NULL, n = 100)
...
```

and returning the results in a vector/array/matrix (if all return values are vectors and the same class) or a `list` (otherwise).

---

Issues where your code is breaking.

- `vec=c(df1[i,],df2[j,],ij.overlap,ij.overlap.95,ij.over,ij.over.95)`  is concatenating strings (from `df1[1,]` and `df2[j,]`) with the numeric return value in `ij.overlap`; see `c("A", 1)` to see what happens to the 1, you should not do this. If you want to combine them into one row, I suggest something like

  ```r
  tmpframe <- data.frame(arg1=df1[i,], arg2=df2[j,], area.1=is.overlap, ...) # fill in rest
  ```
- `mylist[[i]]=vec` is overwriting the previous `j`-iteration each time in the loop, I don't think this is intentional. Instead, you might try `mylist <- c(mylist, list(tmpframe))`, and then after your loops doing your `do.call("rbind", mylist)`.

Comment: Great thank you! I used your last bullet point in your comment and it fixed it. The only thing I had to add was a transpose function t() for the arguments in the tmpframe as ij.overlap give me three rows. Thank you! So I've added the new correct code at the end of my question for anyone who may need it

Comment: If you ignore the second-to-last bullet (numbers converted to strings in a matrix), you are corrupting your data. While you can reverse most of it, it's unnecessary and easily avoided. It's your data.

Comment: yes, sorry I meant that I used your last bullet points, forgot to add the 's' in my previous comment. So both bullet points were what I used for my code fix.

Comment: Your question-edit came after I commented, I saw after-the-fact that you were taking both. I'm glad you found them useful!

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using nested for-loops, you could:

1. Create two ellipse vectors of the same length that you can iterate over simultaneously (df1, df2 in your code).
2. Iterate over the two ellipse vectors (using `purrr::map2()`, or `base::mapply()`) to obtain the results for each ellipse combination.
3. Row bind (`dplyr::bind_rows()`) the results and add the ellipse vectors as columns.

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(GGally)
library(SIBER)

# I got an error for the data you shared is it maybe truncated? Instead, I'm using
# the demo data provided in the `SIBER` package.
data(demo.siber.data)

# Modify the demo data to be more similar to your data.
si.test <- 
  demo.siber.data |> 
  mutate(group = factor(group, label = letters[1:3]),
         community = factor(community, labels = rev(letters)[1:2]))

# The code below should work for your data as is.

siber.test <- createSiberObject(si.test)


# This extracts all group, and community combinations found in the data. Make sure to adjust
# this only to include the combinations you are looking for.
ellipses1 <- 
  distinct(si.test, group, community) |> 
  mutate(ellipse = paste(community, group, sep = ".")) |> 
  pull(ellipse)

# This will create the second ellipse vector.
ellipses2 <- rep_len(ellipses1[1:2], length(ellipses1))

# Using `purrr::map2()` we can simoultanesously iterate over ellipses1 and ellipses2.
# Each iteration feeds one element of each vector into `maxLikOverlap()`.
# `bind_rows()` combines everything into a data.frame/tibble. `mutate()` adds
# the ellipse vectors. `relocate()` places the ellipse columns before the
# value columns.

map2(
  ellipses1,
  ellipses2,
  maxLikOverlap,
  siber.object = siber.test,
  p.interval = NULL,
  n = 100
) |> 
  bind_rows() |> 
  mutate(elipse1 = ellipses1,
         elipse2 = ellipses2) |> 
  relocate(elipse1, elipse2, .before = area.1)
#> # A tibble: 6 × 5
#>   elipse1 elipse2 area.1 area.2 overlap
#>   <chr>   <chr>    <dbl>  <dbl>   <dbl>
#> 1 z.a     z.a      5.99    5.99    5.99
#> 2 z.b     z.b      3.37    3.37    3.37
#> 3 z.c     z.a      5.31    5.99    0   
#> 4 y.a     z.b      0.893   3.37    0   
#> 5 y.b     z.a      3.58    5.99    0   
#> 6 y.c     z.b      0.459   3.37    0
```